# What asterisk functionality is used in `a[href*=`?

Tags: css

I was looking through some code. I came across:

```
.social-navigation a[href*="tumblr.com"]:before {
    content: "\f214";
}
```

This code is used to display social media icons if a link contains tumblr.com in its url. However I have never seen the asterisk used in this way before in css. The only functionality I am aware an asterisk has in css, is the one of universal selector. This seems to do something else akin to a regular expression like: `/.*tumblr\.com.*/g`.

- Can someone explain the functionality of the asterisk used in this example in more detail?

PS: A reference to documentation or a formal name of this functionality would be great. Then I can read up a little more on it and/or try to find more information on the internet.

Comment: Most common CSS attribute selectors are: starts with `^=`, ends with `$=`, and contains `*=`. You can read more about these selectors here: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp

Comment: asterisk selects all elements

Comment: Once I googled ` CSS attribute selector` it was easy to find. Thx Balász.

Comment: @mbadeveloper Not in this context.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does an asterisk before an equal sign mean (\*=) ? What about the exclamation mark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13525542/what-does-an-asterisk-before-an-equal-sign-mean-what-about-the-exclamatio)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most common CSS attribute selectors are:
starts with `^=`
ends with `$=`
and contains `*=`

You can read more about css attribute selectors here: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp

Answer (score 0):

The * is part of the attribute selector operator `*=` : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

So the * itself does not have any meaning or functionality. It is like the != operator in many languages: two characters making one operator.

Comment: Please add an explanation in your answer. As it's written it doesn't explain the behaviour of the selector.

Comment: I think that is not the question posted. I think the original poster thought that the syntax here is `href* = "tumbler.com"`. The answer is that the operator here is `*=` and not `=`

Comment: OP wrote "Can someone explain the functionality of the asterisk used in this example in more detail?". You answered to half of the question.